# hibernate total criterions in a junction

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I fill a junction based on conditions coming from a filter:

```
if (filter.getName() != null) conjunction.add(...);
if (filter.getSurname() != null) conjunction.add(...);
```

At the end add the junction to my Criteria:

```
criteria.add(conjunction);
```

I would like to apply certain aliases to my criteria object only if the total number of criterions in the conjunction are > 0 (to optimize the query):

```
if (moreThanOneCriterion(conjunction)) {
    criteria.createCriteria("users", "user");
    criteria.add(conjunction); 
}
```

How can I know the total number of criterions in a junction ?

As an option, could add a counter variable inside each if block, but looking for a better/cleaner option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik (and according to docs) there's no method to get the number of criterions from a conjunction.

Probably could do something like that

```
boolean moreThanOneCriterion= false;
if (filter.getName() != null) { conjunction.add(...); moreThanOneCriterion=true; }
if (filter.getSurname() != null) { conjunction.add(...); moreThanOneCriterion=true; }
```

and add the alias if `moreThanOneCriterion` is `true` (since it seems you're not really interested in the exact count of criterions)

Comment: right, thanks. I will wait if someone has any other answer. maybe some utility class or a way in hibernate to get that but doesn´t seem it is possible